# What other things did Andy Dufresne carry while escaping from Shawshank Prison?

Tags: the-shawshank-redemption

There were a few things which Andy Dufresne was shown putting into the package which he tied to his foot while escaping. Some of the items were his chess pieces and the account books of the warden. However, during the cell-search the next morning, besides the prison clothes, **a rock hammer and a bar of soap** were discovered to be missing.

The use of account books and rock hammer are apparent but what were the other things that Andy carried and for what purpose?

Comment: What makes you think there were other things?

Comment: Since he was carrying a package while breaking out, he might have needed some items for withdrawing money from the banks and for his forward journey towards the pacific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bar of soap - to wash after he had gotten through the 'tunnel of sh*t'. Rock hammer he had in case he needed to hammer through anything I guess. Clothes were what he was wearing (I'm assuming you mean clothes not cloths)

Comment: I was also wondering whether there was any chance that the soap he was carrying helped him in confusing the sniffer dogs with the smell.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the bar of soap, chess pieces, plus the financial paperwork (not just account books, but also social security card, drivers license etc) and letter to the newspaper, he was also carrying his rock hammer and a change of clothes (suit and white shirt plus dress shoes, "borrowed" from the warden).

Comment: This should have been the chosen answer.  He took items with sentimental value (carving those chess pieces took him, literally, years and kept him sane), as well as practical.

Answer (score 0):

He also took the warden's shirt and suit, plus possibly some underclothes, so he could look like a well-to-do civilian when he visited the banks.